# Highlight the current item on a menu

Tags: javascript, styles

I want to highlight (change class) the item on the menu the user is visiting as most sites do.  But I'm not sure how to do it.

Which is the easiest way? Can I add something like :hover to add a style for the selected item or a script or what?

I'm using a simple plain html menu.

http://chusmix.com/?s=Buenos+Aires

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create a class with a proper name like '.menu-selected' and apply it to the current selected item. it could also have the same style as ':hover' menu style.

Comment: How do I make the item swap to that class when it's selected? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean 'when it's selected'? page corresponding to the menu is active or you just pressed the menu item? for the first case i would add the class to the item on the html (by hand or via server-code). on the second case, some javascript would do the trick.

Comment: I'm not talking of when you are clicking :active but when you are actually on that page. For example if you are in the front page, "home" should be highlighted. I don't know how to do it either way.

Comment: then you should do what i say on my answer. apply the .menu-selected style class to the menu item.

Comment: simply add class="menu-selected" to the tag element.
say it is a li » <li class="menu-selected">home</li>